# WSO2 API Manager: Restrict API Call based on IP address

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can i restrict access token for calling API based on IP. I find the domains restriction in version 1.3 of API-M but i can not find any guide to do so in the  version 2.1. thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available in APIM 2.1.0. You can find details in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Managing+Throttling

Comment: thanks. I find it now, but how can I configure it to perform my requirement in a good way? can I add an advance throttle policy->Add tier->conditional group->IP condition and set IP address to allowed IP and request count to 0 then select invert condition?

Comment: That's one option. You can directly blacklist the ip address as well.